# Do Master of Research programs require prior research experience?

Tags: research-process, graduate-admissions, masters

I have a research question that I want to explore, so am considering completing a Master of Research (MRes) degree in the UK. I will soon finish a terminal master's program by coursework (in the US), with no thesis option, so I do not have a research background. Is research experience a typical prerequisite for an MRes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, you do not need research experience to get on a UK MRes progamme.** Though it will help.

It may vary by institution; this answer is based on the one MRes from my subject area.

The [UCL MRes in Energy Demand Studies](http://www.bartlett.ucl.ac.uk/energy/programmes/postgraduate/mres-energy-demand-studies) has the following prerequisites (taken from that linked page):

> - Good numeracy and literacy and an ability to present ideas clearly
> - An appreciation of the importance of behaviour and society in energy demand
> - An understanding of or ability to learn basic physics and engineering concepts
> - Strong performance in a science, engineering or social sciences discipline

The course, in its first half, contains a lot of taught material. This covers, amongst other things, research skills.

Having research skills, or a research track record, will help you with getting onto the more competitive courses, such as this one; and it will improve your chances of getting your study funded too.

One of the selection criteria is (*ibid*):

> how your academic and professional background meets the demands of this challenging programme

so if you can show a research track record, that will help fulfill that criterion.